# Radial-gradient doesn’t create perfect circles

Tags: html, css, radial-gradients

Sample code:

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, blue 50%, pink 50%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

The edges of the circle are jagged. How can I completely round it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few solutions to this, discussed in [this Medium article](https://medium.com/pixel-and-ink/avoiding-jagged-edges-on-gradients-f485cc7401f5) by
Mandy Michael.

One elegant one is to use `calc` to add a single pixel of the second color, as seen below, which renders enough blur to offset the jaggedness.

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, blue 50%, pink calc(50% + 1px));
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I added 0.5% on the pink and it kind of smoothed out the edges. Hope that's what you are looking for.

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 50%, blue 50%, pink 50.5%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: It doesn’t work on small circles. For example: `div {width: 20px; height: 20px;}`